# Failed to resolve: androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.6

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to use Fetch library to download APK files, when adding the dependency to build.gradle file and sync gradle, I get an error:

> Failed to resolve: androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.6

I get this error usually when using libraries that are old, what causes the error, and are there other libraries for downloading files?

Comment: That [artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.tonyodev.fetch2/xfetch2/3.1.6) is only present in JCenter repository and can be downloaded without problems. Make sure the Jcenter repo is configured in your project. Note that JCenter repo has been closed in 2021. At the moment the artifacts can be downloaded, but it is unsure how long the artifact will be available for download.

Comment: Yes, after adding jCenter it works, it's deprecated though, and android studio recommends me to use mavenCentral instead, that won't cause any problems in the future?

Comment: The artifact is one of those that is not present in Maven Central so you can not switch. AFAIR JCenter was offline for some months, then JFrog decided to bring it back online for an indefinite time: https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown